# VB.net update list items from file

Tags: vb.net, listbox, refresh, readline

I click a button (with this code) to load lines from file "testexam" into a a listbox "lstHere". Testexam will be updated by another program and I want a code to copy new lines of "testexam" to the bottom of "lstHere". Secondly the selected index should come to the first item of the new list. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub
    Dim MReader As New StreamReader("C:\Users\Sparrow\testexam.txt")
    Dim this1 As String = ""
    Dim thisline(6000) As String


    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Do Until MReader.Peek = -1
        this1= MReader.ReadLine

        thisline(i)= this1

        lstHere.Items.Add(thisline(i))

        'go to the next line.
        i = i + 1

    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you use `File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Sparrow\testexam.txt")` to get the full array with a single line?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are trying to implement this, but it works with different buttons.

Button1:

```
'Add the selected item to the top
ListBox1.Items.Insert(0, ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
```

Button2:

```
'Delete duplicates
Dim items(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1) As Object
ListBox1.Items.CopyTo(items, 0)
ListBox1.Items.Clear()
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(items.AsEnumerable().Distinct().ToArray())
```

Comment: Thank you, noidea  and @Tim  Schmelter. I tried but the lstHere.items.Addrange(lines) but it adds all the lines in the updated file. So the listbox will have duplicates of line (from old file and duplicates from update). I want it such that new lines copied at this click did not exist at the time of the last read of the file. Secondly, the selected index should be the first item of this new lines. Thank you.

Comment: new edit ! it works fine, yet you need to prevent non selected items and stuff . Btw, if it suits , mark as answered. Good luck

Comment: Before I click this new button to insert new (updated) lines, the listbox already has a number of list items (read from "testexam" file). I want to append this new lines to the button of the list so every updated line of the file should be part of lines added to the listbox. What should be excluded is lines that have been copied already. For instance if before update of the file, I copied lines AB, CD, EF & GH and after 60seconds new lines (IJ, AB, EF, DG) have been added to the file, this new code or button that I need should copy lines  IJ, AB, EF & DG and append to the list. Thank you.